# Using itext and jfreechart need to create image for legendtitle alone

Tags: itext, jfreechart

Can you please help me to get Image for legendtitle alone ?
I am using pieplot3d & doing customization and later I create legendtitle(plot
when I use draw method
legend.draw(graphics2d,rectangle2d
graphics2.dispose
Image.getInstance(template

I am using jfreechart with Itext & doing as mention below

add image to document or PdfCell its empty.

My requirment is to show plot/chart in seperate cell/table & legend in seperate cell table so that when there is change in size of legenditems size of chart wont change.
Please help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post a small, but runnable piece of code.

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117321).

Comment: Completed this task long back used simple table 3 colums one column with drawing small square image and other two with legend values